# Complex number matrix determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, determinant

> Let $z=a+bi \in \mathbb C$ be a complex number with $a,b \in \mathbb R$, and define
>   $$
> M(z)= \begin{pmatrix} a & -b\\ b & a \end{pmatrix}. 
> $$
>   Show that det($M(z)$) = $|z|, \forall z \in \mathbb C$.

---

I found the determinant to be $a^2+b^2$, but I'm not sure how to incorporate the $z=a+bi \in \mathbb C$ part into the proof.

Comment: If you denote $z=a+bi$, then by definition $|z|^2=a^2+b^2$. I guess there's a typo in some place as $\textrm{det} M(z)=|z|^2$.

Comment: Note the norm of a complex number is it's distance from the origin in the complex plane.

Comment: @corey979 the problem given to me didn't show $|z|^2$

Answer (score 1):

As stated, the problem is wrong. If you consider $a=b=1$, then $\det M=2$, while $|1+i|=\sqrt2. $ The right equality would be $$\det M=|z|^2. $$